# Output variable value

Tags: php

I'm trying to output a variable's string value in php

```
 // sanitizes the string value that's passed in from the sending page
 $cmessage = filter_var($_POST["confmsg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
 $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => "<div style='margin-bottom: 7px; clear:right;'>" . $user_name . ':  </div>echo "$cmessage"'));
```

`$output` is displayed in an alert back on the sending page, but it's displaying as literal text.
 
Example:  `Joe: echo $cmessage`

What do I need to do to get `$cmessage`'s string to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you got your single and double quotes messed up, try this:

```
// sanitizes the string value that's passed in from the sending page
$cmessage = filter_var($_POST["confmsg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => "<div style='margin-bottom: 7px; clear:right;'>$user_name:</div>$cmessage"));
```

**EDIT:**
This migt be a better one fore you and slightly easier to understand

```
// sanitizes the string value that's passed in from the sending page
$cmessage = filter_var($_POST["confmsg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => "<div style='margin-bottom: 7px; clear:right;'>".$user_name.":</div>".$cmessage));
```

Comment: Thanks, quotes always get me.

Answer (score 0):

php strings dont evaluate variables if the string is created by single quotes (') look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php:

```
// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
```